# Why does scala complain when given this pattern match on an integral value?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

**Goal**: Write a function that generates a new String excluding a specified character (identified by the index)

**Example**:

- `takeAllExcept(0, "abc")` returns `bc`
- `takeAllExcept(1, "abc")` returns `ac`
- `takeAllExcept(2, "abc")` returns `ab`

**What I did initially**:

```
def takeAllExcept( index: Int, s: String ): String = {
  val lastIndex = s.length()-1
  index match {
    case 0 => return s.slice(1, s.length)
    case lastIndex => return s.slice(0, s.length()-1)
    case _ => { s.slice(0, index) + s.slice(index+1, s.length) }
  }
}
```

The compiler complains that the statement block for `case _` is unreachable.

**How I fixed it**

```
def takeAllExcept( index: Int, s: String ): String = {
  val lastIndex = s.length()-1
  if( index == 0 )
    return s.slice(1, s.length)

  if( index == lastIndex )
    return s.slice(0, s.length()-1)

  s.slice(0, index) + s.slice(index+1, s.length)
}
```

I want to know why my initial attempt failed with the unreachable code. It looks legit to me. Also, is there an in-built facility in scala that already does this ?

Comment: Does `case lastIndex` create a *new variable* with the same name, instead of matching the value of the existing variable?

Comment: to pattern match against a variable, use its name in backticks

Comment: It has to do with lower-case variable name. Use `LastIndex` instead. IMO, the lower-case "feature" is a big mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lastIndex` in the pattern is an implicit declaration of a new name that is bound to whatever value is put into the match and shadows the allready defined `lastIndex`, as the other two post allready pointed out. There are two other possibilities instead of using upper case identifiers (see Peter's post):

Using backticks to let the compiler know that this shall not be a declaration of a new identifier:

```
case `lastIndex` => ...
```

Using pattern guards:

```
case x if x == lastIndex => ...
```

If you want to do a lot of index-based removing on strings then it would be faster to use a Buffer by calling `toBuffer` on the string and then you can use the `remove(i: Int)` method of Buffer. That is slower for only one operation because you will have to convert the Buffer back to string when your done but if you do many random access operations its a lot faster. After your done you can call `mkString` on the Buffer to get your String back. For single removal I would do it like Peter suggested or here is an alternative:

```
def takeAllExcept(i: Int, s: String) = s.take(i) + s.drop(i+1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your first question:

```
def takeAllExcept( index: Int, s: String ): String = {
  val LastIndex = s.length()-1
  index match {
    case 0 => return s.slice(1, s.length)
    case LastIndex => return s.slice(0, s.length()-1)
    case _ => { s.slice(0, index) + s.slice(index+1, s.length) }
  }
}
```

The `lastIndex` after the `case` is newly bound while pattern matching and hides the definition of `val lastIndex = s.length()-1`. As my example shows, you can use upper case names, then scala uses a defined `val` in scope.

To answer your second question in a way I would solve it:

```
def takeAllExcept(i: Int, s: String): String = {
  val (prefix,suffix) = s.splitAt(i)
  prefix + suffix.tail
}
```

Comment: Your solution is wicked. How do I become as smart as you? :)

Comment: It´s easy: Read "Programming In Scala" book, do some projects yourself, read many, many blogs and stackoverflow entries and never stop trying crazy approaches ;)

Comment: Peter's solution will throw an exception on `suffix.tail` if you provide an `i >= s.length`. My solution (which might not be as efficient, however) would be: `def takeAllExcept(i: Int, s: String) = s.zipWithIndex.filterNot(_._2 == i).map(_._1).mkString`

Answer (score 1):

```
val lastIndex = s.length()-1
index match {
  case 0 => return s.slice(1, s.length)
  case lastIndex => return s.slice(0, s.length()-1)
  case _ => { s.slice(0, index) + s.slice(index+1, s.length) }
}
```

The second clause does not try to match `index` with `lastIndex` as you would have expected from e.g. Prolog. Instead it matches any value and binds the value to the name `lastIndex`, shadowing the previous binding of this variable.