# Pattern match for variable in scope (Scala)

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, bind

In the following code

```
val x = 5
val y = 4 match {
  case x => true
  case _ => false
}
```

the value `y` is true. Scala interprets `x` to be a free variable in the pattern match instead of binding it to the variable with the same name in the scope.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why did you duplicate an existing question and then answer it yourself?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172557/problem-with-scala-matching-scope
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153590/why-does-scala-complain-when-given-this-pattern-match-on-an-integral-value

Comment: @dhg: I could not find that question on SO, that's why. I answer my own question since I prefer using SO as a knowledge repository instead of taking a note on my tiny hidden blog or making a mental post. Thanks for the link, I agree with closing with duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoking the *least astonishment principle*, I will simply do:

```
val x = 5
val y = 4 match {
  case z if z == x => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Ron answer is the good one, you add a condition that can be pattern matched directly. (downvote)

Comment: I think the condition is just as fast, and remember the least astonishment principle. (upvote)

Answer (score 12):

Backticking the variable indicates to bind a scoped variable:

```
val x = 5
val y = 4 match { case `x` => true; case _ => false }
```

returns `false`.

Alternatively, if a variable starts with an uppercase letter, it binds to a scoped variable without backticking.

Comment: see also http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-pattern-matching-proposal-td1999364.html