# Is it possible to use match scala operation with variables?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does pattern matching in Scala not work with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables)
>   [Pattern match for variable in scope (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754579/pattern-match-for-variable-in-scope-scala)

For example I have code

```
def equals(value1:String, value2:String) = value1 match {
 case value2 => true
 case _ => false
}
```

I found workaround, but I do not really like syntax

> ```
> def equals(value1:String, value2:String) = value1 match {
>  case v if v == value2 => true
>  case _ => false
> }
> ```

Comment: possible [dublicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables). See Ben James answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

bracket value2 with backticks:

```
case `value2` => true
```

Comment: thanks, looks like trick. I think this behavior can be removed in future versions....